# VBA countifs using multiple Arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

I an looking to find a value from countifs ,using an array of dates and an array of names.

""Shout out to Jeeped for providing the code for date array below.""

```
Dim d As Long, dts As Variant
ReDim dts(DateSerial(2019, 1, 1) - DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) + 1)
    dts(0) = vbNullString
For d = DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) To DateSerial(2018, 12, 31)
    dts(d - DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) + 1) = Format(d, "m/d/yyyy") '<~~should match worksheet
Next d

R = Application.Sum(Application.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "Stuff", Range("B:B"), dts, Range("C:C"), Array("Name1", "Name2")))
```

The result is always zero, and "I think?" its because both of the arrays are of different types? or maybe format is a better word.

I can use the dts array in similar countifs ...see below.

```
Z = Application.Sum(Application.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "stuff", Range("B:B"), dts))
```

however as soon as I need to introduce another array for say "names", the countifs line will execute and the code runs, but.. just returns zero.

```
R = Application.Sum(Application.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "Stuff", Range("B:B"), dts, Range("C:C"), Array("Name1", "Name2")))
```

How can I create an array of "names" that would work with the dts array in a countifs situation?

Thanks!

Edit 4/2/2018 1:00pm
Adding Example to show that changing the order still returns 0.

within worksheet use this, or re-order for the other line commented out in the code below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lLWa.png)
Then using either the active line of the one commented out.

```
Public Sub Broken()
'****************************************************************
Dim d As Long, dts As Variant
ReDim dts(DateSerial(2019, 1, 1) - DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) + 1)
dts(0) = vbNullString
For d = DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) To DateSerial(2018, 12, 31)
dts(d - DateSerial(2018, 1, 1) + 1) = Format(d, "m/d/yyyy") '<~~should match 
worksheet
Next d
'****************************************************************

        'Answer = Application.Sum(Application.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "Z*", Range("B:B"), dts, Range("C:C"), Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5")))

        Answer = Application.Sum(Application.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), dts, Range("B:B"), "Z*", Range("C:C"), Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5")))

        MsgBox Answer, vbInformation
End Sub
```

****The answer should be 2

*Date To be within 2018 Or Blank from dts Array
*a Column to contain "Z"
*a Column to contain a name from name Array

Comment: if you use `Application.CountIfs function` then the matches will need to be on the same row rather than just anywhere in the other columns/array

Comment: Thanks,  They are on the same row though. I am essentially trying to count records that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countifs-method-excel) for the `WorksheetFunction` commands isn't great. It's a good idea to refer to the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) for the related  worksheet function. (ie., `COUNTIFS` vs `Application.WorksheetFunction.Countifs`)

Looks like your added criteria are out of order.

---

### **`COUNTIFS`** Syntax

```
COUNTIFS( criteria_range1, criteria1 
        [,criteria_range2, criteria2
        [,criteria_range3, criteria3
        [,criteria_range4, criteria4]]] … )
```

The **`COUNTIFS`** function syntax has the following arguments:

- **`criteria1`** *(Required)* The first range in which to evaluate the associated criteria.
- **`criteria1`** *(Required)* The criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be counted.
  For example, criteria can be expressed as `32`, `">32"`, `B4`, `"apples"`, or `"32"`.
- **`[criteria_range2, criteria2,] ...`** *(Optional)* Additional ranges and their associated criteria.
  Up to `127` range/criteria pairs are allowed.

**Important:**

- Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the `criteria_range1` argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [WorksheetFunction.CountIfs Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countifs-method-excel)
- Office.com : [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) (with video)

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. By order do you mean the filters have to cascade? If so, then yes they already do. Actually even if I switch the order the result should be be same, at least it is if I do the filtering manually in the worksheet.